# Write numbers from file to array in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua

I have a file which looks the following:

```
some text
184 3.7872  184 2.5076
185 3.7891  185 2.5063
186 3.7912  186 2.5042
```

I want to skip the first line and write the data into an array.

What I've got so far:

```
local file = io.open("test.txt", "r");
local readFile = {}
for line in file:lines() do
   table.insert (readFile, line);
end

--initialise target array
local array = {}
for i=2,# readFile,1 do
   array[i-1] = {}
   for j=1,4,1 do
      array[i][j] = 0
   end
end

for i=2,# readFile,1 do
   --split lines from readFile
   --write numbers into target array
end
```

It seems that when I want to initialise the array there is some error which I don't understand:

```
lua: script.lua:13: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')
stack traceback:
    script.lua:13: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Can someone help me here? Also when I call readFile[2] for example I get 184 3.7872  184 2.5076 which I have to split and write to the array. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate it.

```
local file = io.open("test.txt", "r");
local array = {}
for line in file:lines() do
    local t = {}
    for s in line:gmatch("%S+") do
        t[#t+1] = tonumber(s)
    end
    array[#array+1] = t
end
```

And, here is a bit of a poor explanation of what I changed.

```
local file = io.open("test.txt", "r");
-- local readFile = {} Don't need this either.
local array = {} -- Init it here, cleaner and easier.
for line in file:lines() do
    local t = {} -- This is our line in the array.
    for s in line:gmatch("%S+") do -- Iterate through the string in blocks of non-whitespace. Check the Lua Patterns Matching Tutorial online.
        t[#t+1] = tonumber(s)
    end
    array[#array+1] = t

    --[[ If you want to just have the numbers, without caring about the newlines, just do

    for s in line:gmatch("%S+") do
        array[#array+1] = tonumber(s)
    end

    instead]]
end

-- Snipping that bottom part, we can do this much more efficiently.
```

Some tips,

- Lua Arrays/Tables do not need to be initialized, they're dynamic.
- Your error came from Trying to index array[i], when you initialized array[i-1].
- in `for i=a, b, c do` loops, `c` only needs to be specified if it's not `1`. So `for i=1, #lines do` works as well.
- # is not a function, it's an indexing (Technically). It just looks cleaner if you pair it with the thing it's counting. `#lines` instead of `# lines`

Answer (score 0):

The following does the trick, but is very inefficient:

```
local file = io.open("test.txt", "r");
local readFile = {}
for line in file:lines() do
   table.insert (readFile, line);
end

--initialise target array
local array = {}
for i=1,(#readFile)-1,1 do
   array[i] = {}
   for j=1,4,1 do
      array[i][j] = 0
   end
end

function string:split( inSplitPattern, outResults )
   if not outResults then
      outResults = { }
   end
   local theStart = 1
   local theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern,     theStart )
   while theSplitStart do
      table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart,    theSplitStart-1 ) )
      theStart = theSplitEnd + 1
      theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
   end
   table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart ) )
   return outResults
end

local myTable = readFile[2]:split(" ")
for i = 1, #myTable do
   print( myTable[i] ) -- This will give your needed output
end
```

If someone has a more efficient way I would be also happy.